# Error on installing Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04 > SOLVED

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04

I would like to install Python 3.9 on my Ubuntu 20.04.

So, I tried following this steps:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu

But, I have the following error:

```
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ ./configure ––enable–optimizations
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: ––enable–optimizations
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `––enable–optimizations': machine
`––enable–optimizations' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ––enable–optimizations failed
```

Whatever I try I have so many other errors. Maybe it's a problem about configuration on my OS.

I expect not to break Stack rules with this question but I don't really know how to handle this.

PS: Files on Python 3.9 are the following:

- aclocal.m4
- config.sub
- Grammar
- LICENSE
- Misc
- Parser
- pyconfig.h.in
- Tools CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
- configure
- Include
- m4
- Modules
- PC
- Python
- config.guess
- configure.ac
- install-sh
- Mac
- netlify.toml
- PCbuild
- README.rstconfig.log
- Doc
- Lib
- Makefile.pre.in
- Objects
- Programs
- setup.py

PS_2: I have Python 3.8 and I would like to install 3.9 but I got a lot of errors. Installing from source code is what I did last time and it was easy.

I just tried that and it doesn't work.

PS_3: I tried to install using hhe package manager and it's the same result, please just quit me more reputation but help a novice to get what I am doing wrong

```
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] contraseña para jordiba90: 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
software-properties-common ya está en su versión más reciente (0.98.9.2).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
 This PPA contains more recent Python versions packaged for Ubuntu.

Disclaimer: there's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server), you do so at your own risk.

Update Note
===========
Please use this repository instead of ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes.

Reporting Issues
================

Issues can be reported in the master issue tracker at:
https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues

Supported Ubuntu and Python Versions
====================================

- Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) Python 2.3 - Python 2.6, Python 3.1 - Python3.4, Python 3.6 - Python3.9
- Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) Python2.3 - Python 2.6, Python 3.1 - Python 3.5, Python3.7 - Python3.9
- Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) Python3.5 - Python3.7, Python3.9
- Note: Python2.7 (all), Python 3.5 (xenial), Python 3.6 (bionic), Python 3.8 (focal) are not provided by deadsnakes as upstream ubuntu provides those packages.
- Note: for focal, older python versions require libssl1.0.x so they are not currently built

The packages may also work on other versions of Ubuntu or Debian, but that is not tested or supported.

Packages
========

The packages provided here are loosely based on the debian upstream packages with some modifications to make them more usable as non-default pythons and on ubuntu.  As such, the packages follow debian's patterns and often do not include a full python distribution with just `apt install python#.#`.  Here is a list of packages that may be useful along with the default install:

- `python#.#-dev`: includes development headers for building C extensions
- `python#.#-venv`: provides the standard library `venv` module
- `python#.#-distutils`: provides the standard library `distutils` module
- `python#.#-lib2to3`: provides the `2to3-#.#` utility as well as the standard library `lib2to3` module
- `python#.#-gdbm`: provides the standard library `dbm.gnu` module
- `python#.#-tk`: provides the standard library `tkinter` module

Third-Party Python Modules
==========================

Python modules in the official Ubuntu repositories are packaged to work with the Python interpreters from the official repositories. Accordingly, they generally won't work with the Python interpreters from this PPA. As an exception, pure-Python modules for Python 3 will work, but any compiled extension modules won't.

To install 3rd-party Python modules, you should use the common Python packaging tools.  For an introduction into the Python packaging ecosystem and its tools, refer to the Python Packaging User Guide:
https://packaging.python.org/installing/

Sources
=======
The package sources are available at:
https://github.com/deadsnakes/

Nightly Builds
==============

For nightly builds, see ppa:deadsnakes/nightly https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/nightly
 Más información: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Pulse [ENTRAR] para continuar o Ctrl+C para cancelar la adición.

0% [Trabajando]
Obj:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Des:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]  
Des:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98,3 kB]
Des:6 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Des:7 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [229 kB]
Des:8 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [205 kB]
Des:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]
Des:10 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.764 B]
Des:11 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24,3 kB]
Des:12 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [56,6 kB]
Descargados 835 kB en 2s (440 kB/s)                                    
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ 
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ sudo apt-get update
Obj:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Obj:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Obj:6 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ sudo apt-get install python3.9
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
python3.9 ya está en su versión más reciente (3.9.0-5~20.04).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
jordiba90@lts:~/Descargas/Python-3.9.0$
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.9.0. But instead of investing too much time with this issue, you could either run `./configure` without the `--enable-optimizations` flag or simply install via the packet manager as dejdej is suggesting.

Comment: I had to guess some things while cleaning up the formatting; please review.

Comment: The guide you are following is not for 3.9, but this `configure` command you tried to use should apparently work for 3.9 too. The error message looks like you simply have the wrong `configure` script. Are you sure it's the one from the 3.9 tarball?

Comment: I am really sorry triplee, but I tried to specify and detail a question according to what I did and I think it was not vague. You just seem very comprehensive with a novice, so sure that I will be motivated to participate again here.. Thanks, really.

Comment: The last command worked, but it did not replace `python3`. Probably try `python3.9 --version` and perhaps `update-alternatives` if you want to make that the default Python 3 system-wide.

Comment: Ok, what it happened is that I was just trying to execute 'python 3 --version' and I got 'Python 3.8.5' but I didn't specify 'python3.9 --version' and now that I did I got 'Python 3.9.0+'. OK, I installed Python correctly from the begining but I didn't understand why I was not able to check for the version 3.9. So, topic closed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for which you want to install python from source code?

Otherwise just install it using the package manager:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.9
```

Comment: Problem with this is that `software-properties-common` installs python 3.8 and then you have 2 versions in the system